# Vagrant memory customization does not work

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04, vagrantfile

In my Vagrantfile, I am trying to customize the memory of the VirtualBox VM using the following code snippet. I am using the following box for the VM - http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/trusty/current/trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box

```
Vagrant.configure("1") do |config|
    config.vm.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 1024]
end

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
      v.name = "FJORD_VM"
      v.memory = 1024
    end
end
```

But this does not work and the VM starts with the default 512MB RAM. What could be the issue here? I am using the latest 1.7.2 Vagrant. I have also tried using

```
v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 1024]
```

in the `Vagrant.configure("2")` block and still it does not work.

I also intercepted the calls to `VBoxManage` by creating my local wrapper script that logs the arguments before calling the actual `VBoxManage`. I see no calls to customize the VM memory.

Comment: You should remove the first block as that is [telling Vagrant that your Vagrantfile is a 1.0x Vagrantfile](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/version.html). Having both in the same Vagrantfile could be causing some issues.

Comment: Same problem here. Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I second what @ydaetskcoR says about removing the 1.0 section - not only might it confuse Vagrant but it seems redundant. I am using the same box as you and it's working just fine for me:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.memory = 1024
    v.cpus = 2
    v.customize [ :guestproperty, :set, :id, "/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VBoxService/--timesync-set-threshold", 10000 ]
end
```

I am also using Vagrant 1.7.2 and Virtualbox 4.3.16, and as I said, it's working fine for me.

Comment: But how do I maintain compatibility for the older configuration version?

Comment: Do you really have folks with 1.0.x version of vagrant? I question whether it's worthwhile, but if this is indeed the source of your problem, and you *need* to keep support (as opposed to just using require_version), then you could put some Ruby in your config file like `if Vagrant::VERSION[0,3] == "1.0"` to wrap around your old block.

Answer (score 0):

As you can use Vagrant 1.7.2 you just need `Vagrant.configure("2")`, as [here](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/version.html)

So, you can use:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
       v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
       v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--name", "FJORD_VM"]
    end
end
```

Comment: But how do I maintain compatibility for the older configuration version?

Comment: Vagrant alredy maintain compatibility with older version